# How to Fade Transparency in Animation, and hence record in frames, frame by frame?

Tags: rendering, animation, materials, blender-internal-render-engine

I have rendered this no loop GIF using Blender Render.

[image]

I want to:

1) Make the envelope invisible at the first frame.

2) Make it fade in so that it's transparency is at zero when it reaches the center.

3) Make it fade out when is goes back up.

Lets consider. I have placed a Plane1 in front of all objects, and I want to animate the plane to be...

1) Opaque to translucent. (say 0-20 frames)

2) Translucent to transparent. (say 20-40 frames)

3) Transparent to translucent. (say 100-120 frames)

4) Translucent to opaque. (say 120-140 frames)

Answer (score 0):

What you could do animate a a plane with mix shader with a transparent and diffuse and animate the factor value so that it goes from fully transparent to diffuse and have the background transparent then overlay it in the video editor. There probably another way but this how I would do it.

Comment: They are using Blender Internal which doesn't have shaders like Cycles.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't there yet when I was answering.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to go about this would probably be the compositor. First, change your view to the node editor and activate composition:
[image: Settings to activate image composition]
Next, add a mix node in between the render layer input and the output:
[image: Mix node in between the input and output of the compositor]
By default, the second mix input will be white. This makes it so that changing the slider will fade between the image and white. 0 is fully the image, 1 is fully white. This can be used to achieve your effect of fading out the envelope. To make it animated, simply press 'i' while hovering over the 'fac' slider to keyframe it.

Additionally, to make the fading linear, first select the mix node. Then go to the graph editor, and you should see this:
[image: The default graph blender gives for two keyframes.]
Now press 'T' and select 'Linear':
[image: A linear curve]
This produces a much better result for the particular effect you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Yes this helped. I used another way by selecting the respective frames, and then right clicking on desired property (like tranparency, diffuse) in material tab of object. Thank you so much everyone. May you share some best tutorials to teach me the method ( mix shade method) you described? I will be very thankful.